# Ширина блока по размеру текста

Tags: css, css3

Как сделать так, чтобы ширина блока `узнать больше` была по размеру текста?

```css
html,body{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;

  font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
}

div{
  overflow: hidden;
}

.middle{
  display:flex;
  justify-content:center;
  align-items:center;
}

.top_part {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: url("http://5gfuture.ru/wp-content/uploads/2017/08/truck-2391940_1280.jpg") center center no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}
.top_part .top_part_middle {
  width: 65%;
}
.top_part .top_part_middle .top_part_left {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 80%;
}
.top_part .top_part_middle .top_part_left .top_part_left_text {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
.top_part .top_part_middle .top_part_left .top_part_left_text h1 {
  font-size: 50px;
  font-weight: 600;
  color: white;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
.top_part .top_part_middle .top_part_left .top_part_left_text a {
  background-color: #e01f3d;
  color: white;
}
.top_part .top_part_middle .top_part_right {
  width: 20%;
}
```

```html
<div class="top_part middle">
    <div class="top_part_middle">
        <div class="top_part_left">
            <div class="top_part_left_text">
                <!-- Этот текст должен меняться-->
                <h1>lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipiscing</h1>
                <a href="#">Узнать больше</a>
            </div>
            <div class="top_part_left_list">
                <div class="top_part_list">
                    <img src="" alt="">
                    <h1>lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipiscing</h1>
                </div>
                <div class="top_part_list">
                    <img src="" alt="">
                    <h1>lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipiscing</h1>
                </div>
                <div class="top_part_list">
                    <img src="" alt="">
                    <h1>lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipiscing</h1>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="top_part_right">
            <!-- здесь будет форма-->
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вы сами задали 100%

```
.top_part .top_part_middle .top_part_left .top_part_left_text a {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #e01f3d;
  color: white;
}
```

UPD: Это потому что элемент по умолчанию stretch, задайте блоку

```
.top_part_left_text {
  align-items: flex-start; 
}
```